# Need to solve integration using Python scripts (similar to int [a+x(t) dt] )

Tags: python, integration

[image]

How to solve this equation using python

[image: please opne this fig]

Comment: Use brackets to break it up in parts

Comment: Do you need symbolic or numerical integration? In other words, given a function x(t), do you expect a symbolic expression or a number?

Comment: I need a symbolic expression

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x):
    return x**2

ans, err = quad(integrand, 0, 1)
print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also,

```
from scipy.integrate import quad as q
sol,e = q(lambda x: x**2, 0, 1)
print sol
```